# hide eyes and mouth of a image when upload

Tags: javascript, php, image-processing

I am designing a website fro one of my client where they will be uploading user images and with security. It means user will upload their image and the eyes and mouth of the image should be covered with black strip to view from exposure before it saves into database, I am using HTML, CSS, Php, Mysql, Javascript and AJAX, Kindly let me know a solution on this.

Comment: can't you just blur it? that would be super easy to code...

Comment: Will it blur only the eyes and mouth of a photo

Answer (score 0):

There are image processing APIs like IMagik but you'll have to create the algorithm for eyes and mount detection.

From my knowledge Pittsburgh Pattern Recognition have a nice SDK for face recognition http://web.archive.org/web/20090402125011/http://www.pittpatt.com/products/ftr_sdk/sdk_users_guide.html, you may combine both solutions